# How to show a fragment for a few second and hide it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement a fragment as a splash screen, it will be shown for less than 1 second and it will replace itself with an interstitial ad. I want to implement Admob's suggested way of showing interstitial ads. I want to display '**App Loading**' screen inside a fragment and hide the fragment when ad is ready. I am doing it inside a fragment instead of a view becuase I need to make this a generic solution and then add it to the my other apps as well.

[image: Example from Admob]

Comment: unrelated, but that's a strong uninstall driver, what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into the onCreate of your Interstitial ad put this code

```
// This time is in milliseconds
final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Code to start new activity and finish this one
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your code here
            }
        }, TIME_OUT_IN_MILLIS);
```